Cumulative sum with offset
I am working on developing a machine learning model to predict the score for a given team. I want to create a column tracking each team's cumulative score for their home games up to but not including the current game (row). I can easily calculate the cumulative total, but I want to offset the cumulative total to show the cumulative up to but not including the current game below is an example of the dataset. I would ideally like to create the cumulative column



game_id
game_date
home_id
home_score
cumulative




718730
2023-04-03
145
3
0


718695
2023-04-05
145
7
3


718687
2023-04-06
145
6
10


718683
2023-04-06
109
2
0


718671
2023-04-07
109
6
2


718656
2023-04-08
109
12
8



The code below is what I have done so far to create a cumulative total
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('game_data.csv')
data['home_cumulative'] = data.groupby('home_id')['home_score'].cumsum()

I have attempted the below with results not matching what I would excpect
data['home_offset'] = data.groupby('home_id')['home_score'].shift(periods = 1).cumsum().fillna(0)


You can use:
data['cumulative'] = (data.groupby('home_id')['home_score']
                    .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(1))
                    .fillna(0)
                    .astype(int))

to give:
   game_id    game_date  home_id  home_score  cumulative
0   718730  2023-04-03       145           3         0
1   718695  2023-04-05       145           7         3
2   718687  2023-04-06       145           6        10
3   718683  2023-04-06       109           2         0
4   718671  2023-04-07       109           6         2
5   718656  2023-04-08       109          12         8


You basically had the right idea, just slightly off on the code:
data['home_offset'] = data.groupby('home_id')['home_cumulative'].shift(1).fillna(0)


I'd break it down into two steps:
For calculating the cumulative sum,
data['cumulative'] = data.groupby(['home_id'])['home_score'].cumsum()
For offsetting the the sum,
data['offset_cumulative'] = data.groupby(['home_id']['cumulative'].shift(1,fill_value=0)
